# Css3 viewport property

Tags: html, css

I'm testing css3 viewport property. I've prepared 2 versions of the test site the one with `meta` tag with `viewport` property and the second without `meta ... viewport`. Here is the test side code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0">
        <title>blah</title>
        <style>
            div {
                background-color: red;
                width: 980px;
                height: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>viewport</p>
        <div></div>
        <img src="smile.gif">       
    </body>
</html>
```

The `smile.gif` image is 600x600px. The second version just have no `<meta name="viewport"...` line. 
The `viewport` property seems not to work because whether I change the value of `width` or `initial-scale` the site look the always the same. I'm testing on Android tablet and smartphone.

Comment: With `initial-scale=2.0` you should be able to zoom *out* to a larger (x2) screen

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what You mean "zoom out to a larger (x2) screen"?

Comment: You pinch out to zoom in, and pinch in to zoom out.

Comment: Ok but both versions of the site behaves exactly the same. Just like there is  no viewport property.